# Getting empty data while trying to get desired format of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object

```
"data" : [
       {
          "name" : "Heading",
          "text" : "Text Heading",
          "type" : "string",
          "values" : [
             "Arthur"
          ]
       },
       {
          "name" : "Source",
          "text" : "Source Reference",
          "type" : "string",
          "values" : [
             "Jhon"
          ]
       },
       {
          "name" : "Place",
          "text" : "Bank Building",
          "type" : "string",
          "values" : [
             "Mark"
          ]
       },
       {
          "name" : "Animal",
          "text" : "Branch",
          "type" : "string",
          "values" : [
             "Susan"
          ]
       }
]
```

there is a function i am passing the object and an array as the arguments

```
fieldArray=["Heading", "Animal"]
myFunction(fieldArray, data){
... your code here
}
```

I need to get the output  in the below format where I have to search the object with the fields in myArray with the name key of data. Then I need to put the value of the searched object in the below format

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "cells": [{
            "id": "ConstId",
            "cellContent": "Heading"
        },
        {
            "id": "ConstValue",
            "cellContent": "Arthur"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "cells": [{
            "id": "ConstId",
            "cellContent": "Animal"  
        },
        {
            "id": "ConstValue", //a constant field name as ConstValue
            "cellContent": "Susan" // the value of the second field in the myArray from object with name Animal
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I have tried this

```
  const getFormattedData = (fieldArray: any, data: any) => {
        let innerData: any = [];
        for (let i=0; i<fieldArray.length; i++){
                const indexNumber = data.find((key: any) => key.name === fieldArray[i])
                 if(indexNumber != undefined){
                    innerData.push({
                        id: i+1,
                        cells:[{
                        id: 'inquiryName',
                        cellContent: indexNumber.name
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'value',
                        cellContent: indexNumber.values.toString()
                    }
                ] 
                })
        }
        console.log('innerData :>> ', innerData);
    }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like some kind of typescript? You need to make a [mcve]

Comment: what are `ConstId` and `ConstValue`? Are they just constant string?

Comment: these are just constant strings

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below. Since you tagged javascript, posting answer in JS.

```
function formatData(data, fieldArray) {
  let ret = [];
  
  fieldArray.forEach((field, i) => {
    let dataObj = data.filter(d => d.name === field)[0]
    if( dataObj ) {
      ret.push({
        "id": 1,
        "cells": [{
                "id": "ConstId",
                "cellContent": field
            },
            {
                "id": "ConstValue",
                "cellContent": dataObj.values[0] //Put whole obj or just first
            }
        ]
      })
    }
  })
  return ret;
}
```

Link to [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GONdyLvNukWE3Wge?open=lib%2Fscript.js)